# The product of two projections is 0

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm reading a paper and the paper seems to think the following is obvious:

Let $S$ be a semigroup of partial isometries. 
Let $R = \{ E \in P(S) \cup Q(S) : E$ is minimal in $P(S) \cup Q(S)$ and for some $ U \in S,  P_U = Q_U = E \} $. If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are distinct elements in $R$ then $E_1 E_2 =0$.

Since $S$ is a semigroup I know that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are commuting projections and therefore $E_1 E_2$ is a projection. The assertion is clear if I can show that $E_1 E_2$ is in $P(S) \cup Q(S)$, but I don't see how to do this.